# Small question about the notation used in Probability involving two or more random variables.

Tags: probability, notation

So suppose you have two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ and the goal is to find the distribution of $Z=X+Y.$

Now, I saw one formula which states that 
$$P(Z=N)=\sum_{k=0}^{N}P(X=N-k,Y=k).$$
I am not sure how to read $P(X=N-k,Y=k)$ in English. Is it $P(X=N-k)$ and $P(Y=k)$ except it is not since in the next line I see that 
$$P(Z=N)=\sum_{k=0}^{N}P(X=N-k,Y=k) = \sum_{k=0}^{N}P(X=N\cap Y=k)P(Y=k).$$ So why use the comma notation? What does it really mean?

Comment: It means "and" (as in $\land$). That both $X=N-k$ and $Y=k$ happen. It's natural to use comma instead, and you often see that this is the case. It's not only in probability, but math in general

Comment: Yeah but the intersection also means "and", right?

Comment: Could you link me the paper you read that from? Intersection seems more suspicious than the actual comma.

Comment: I mean I did not read this but heard my professor talk like this.

Comment: The comma means intersection (or "and").